# Recurrence and Fibonacci: $a_{n+1}=\frac {1+a_n}{2+a_n}$

Tags: recurrence-relations, fibonacci-numbers

For the recurrence relation 
$$a_{n+1}=\frac {1+a_n}{2+a_n}$$
where $a_1=1$, the solution is $a_n=\frac {F_{2n}}{F_{2n+1}}$, where $F_n$ is the $n$-th Fibonacci number, according to the convention where $F_1=0, F_2=1,\cdots
$

This can easily be proven by substituting the solution back into the recurrence relation, or alternatively by induction.

> Can the solution be **derived directly  from the recurrence relation itself,** i.e.  not by substituting the solution into the recurrence, or by induction?

Comment: i really dont know why this got downvoted .. so sad !! i think the question is really nice (+1)

Comment: @AhmadBazzi neither do I but thanks for the encouraging comment and upvote! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it can be derived directly, assuming some familiarity with the Fibonacci numbers. I am using the initial conditions $F_1=F_2=1$ for the Fibonacci numbers, which impies that
$$
a_{n}=\frac{F_{2n-1}}{F_{2n}}
$$

There is a nice property involving functions of the form 
$$
f(x) = \frac{ax+b}{cx+d}
$$
If you compose such an $f$ with another $g(x)=\frac{px+q}{sx+t}$ of the same form, the result is another function in the same form, whose coefficients are identical to *matrix product* of the squares of coefficients of $f$ and $g$:
$$
f\circ g = \frac{(ap+bs)x+(aq+bt)}{(cp+ds)x+(cq+dt)}
$$
Letting 
$$
f(x)=\frac{1+x}{2+x}
$$
this implies that 
$$a_n=f\circ f\circ \dots \circ f\big(1\big),$$ with $n-1$ functions composed. Using the matrix connection, and the observation that substituting $x=1$ results in a fraction whose numerator  and denominator are the components of the right column of this matrix, this implies that $a_n$ is a fraction whose numerator an denominator are given by the matrix
$$
a_n=\frac{b_n}{c_n},\qquad \begin{bmatrix}b_n\\c_n\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&2\end{bmatrix}^{n-1}\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}^{2(n-1)}\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}
$$
Finally, recall that $\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}$ is the "Fibonacci matrix" which satisfies
$$
\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}^n=\begin{bmatrix}F_{n-1}&F_n\\F_{n}&F_{n+1}\end{bmatrix},
$$
an identity which follows directly from the recurrence $F_n=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}$ and base cases $F_0=0,F_1=1$.

Comment: Thanks. Very nice solution (+1). Interesting property of $f(x)$ and clever application.

Answer (score 8):

Hint:
By letting $2+a_n=\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}$, we get
$$\frac{b_{n+2}}{b_{n+1}}-2 = 1 - \frac{b_{n}}{b_{n+1}} \implies b_{n+2} -3b_{n+1} + b_{n} = 0.$$

Comment: Thanks (+1). Nice hint. At least that gets us to a nice linear recurrence relation.

Comment: clever substitution (+1)

Answer (score 1):

[*My interpretation of Mike Earnest's solution, posted here for my own reference only*]

$$\begin{align}
a_{n+1}&=\frac {b_{n+1}}{c_{n+1}}=\frac {1+\frac {b_n}{c_n}}{2+\frac {b_n}{c_n}}=\frac {b_n+c_n}{b_n+2c_n}\\\\
\left(b_{n+1}\atop c_{n+1}\right)
&=\left(1\ \ 1\atop 1\ \  2\right)\left(b_{n}\atop c_{n}\right)
=\left(1\ \ 1\atop 1\ \  2\right)^2\left(b_{n-1}\atop c_{n-1}\right)=\cdots\\\\
&=\left(1\ \ 1\atop 1\ \  2\right)^n\left(b_1\atop c_1\right)\\\\
&=\left(0\ \ 1\atop 1\ \  1\right)^{2n}\left(b_1\atop c_1\right)\\\\
&=\left(F_{2n-1}\ \ F_{2n}\ \ \ \atop F_{2n}\ \ \ \  F_{2n+1}\right)\left(1\atop 1\right)
&&\scriptsize(a_1=1\Rightarrow b_1=1, c_1=1)\\\\
&=\left(F_{2n-1}+F_{2n}\ \ \ \atop F_{2n}\ \ \ +F_{2n+1}\right)\\\\
&=\left(F_{2n+1}\atop F_{2n+2}\right)\\\\
\therefore a_{n+1}&=\frac {b_{n+1}}{c_{n+1}}=\frac {F_{2n+1}}{F_{2n+2}}\\\\
\color{red}{a_n}&\color{red}{=\frac {F_{2n}\ \ \ }{F_{2n+1}}\qquad\blacksquare}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $b_n=\frac{1}{a_n}$. We have
$$ b_n = \frac{a_n+2}{a_n+1} = \frac{2b_n+1}{b_n+1}=1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{b_n}} $$
hence in terms of continued fractions we have $b_1=[1], b_2=[1;1,1], b_3=[1;1,1,1,1]$ and so on. The convergents of $\varphi=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}=[1;\overline{1}]$ are given by ratios of consecutive Fibonacci numbers, hence $b_n=\frac{F_{2n-1}}{F_{2n+1}}$ and $a_n=\frac{F_{2n}}{F_{2n+1}}$.

Comment: Thanks. If a series $c_n$ converges to $\phi$ as $n\to \infty$, can it be concluded that $c_n=\frac {F_n}{F_{n+1}}$, since we know that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac {F_n}{F_{n+1}}=\phi$, or is this not necessarily the case?

Comment: That is definitely not always true. For example, each of the series $c_n = \dfrac{F_n-1}{F_{n+1}}$, $d_n = \dfrac{F_{n+1}}{F_{n+2}}$, $e_n = \dfrac{F_n}{F_{n+1}-1000}$, and $f_n = \sqrt{\dfrac{F_n}{F_{n+2}}}$ converges to $\phi = \dfrac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}$. There are also many series which converge to $\phi$ which aren't expressible in "nice" closed forms.